# ECS Fargate Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, cost-management

I'd like to make sure I'm interpreting AWS's ECS Fargate pricing model correctly when compared to an m4.large EC2 instance (2vCPU, 8GB Mem) running non stop (even dropping to 1% cpu/mem utilization) for an entire month (730hrs).

```
# Monthly cost estimates

Fargate:
    cpu = 730hrs * 2vCPU * $0.056 = $73.88
    mem = 730hrs * 8GB Mem * $0.0127 = $74.17
    total = $73.88 + $74.17 = $148.05

EKS ec2 node (1 yr reserved no upfront):
    total = 730hrs * $0.062 = $45.26

EKS ec2 node (on demand):
    total = 730hrs * $0.10 = $73.00
```

It appears Fargate would be ~3x as expensive as an EC2 instance. Does my Fargate pricing look accurate? I'm assuming Fargate isn't intended to be used for something like a 24/7 website, but more like a one off job, analogous perhaps to a Lamba function that runs a container image.

Am I correct that I'm billed for the entire Fargate task cpu & mem allocation, regardless if I'm utilizing 1% or 100% of the resources?

References:

- https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/

Comment: If you are running stable workload, indeed a dedicated ECS / EKS cluster is more effective (mainly if you can apply an RI). IMHO Fargate is feasible if you need scalability to cover peek workloads..

Comment: Yea fargate isn't meant for 24/7, you will be billed for full price regardless of utilization

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your calculations seem correct to me.

I run a bunch of 24/7 websites as 0.25vCPU and 0.5GB RAM Fargate tasks just because of the ease of setting them up. They don't have lots of traffic and they are cached pretty heavily, but if they need to they can scale to 10x based on target CPU.

Used that way I think they are pretty cost efficient.

Update:
AWS updated Fargate prices January 7, 2019. 
The prices now are $0.04048 per vCPU per hour and $0.004445 per GB memory per hour. 
Your example would now be:

```
Fargate:
  cpu = 730hrs * 2vCPU * $0.04048 = $59.10
  mem = 730hrs * 8GB Mem * $0.004445 = $25.96
  total = $59.10 + $25.96 = $85.06
```

Comment: That's the same usage profile I settled on: configure the service to use the minimum it needs to serve the first request and have it aggressively auto-scale upwards under load.

For a task that's mostly idle, any load spikes that cause scaling will be noise in the overall cost - as such, I view the idle costs as the cost of running a persistent service.

Comment: In addition to what's already been said in this answer I'd like to point out that comparing raw ec2 capacity with fargate tasks isn't an apple to apple from resources perspective. In theory all fargate capacity can be devoted to run your application (sidecars aside) whereas EC2 capacity is gross capacity that is intended to be distributed to tasks at run time. It's not uncommon to see EC2 container instances running at very low utilization for a number of reasons that would not apply to Fargate tasks.